# How to unite values of list by first item value in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following data:

```
[
 {'sam@yahoo.com', 7007, '1'},
 {'sam@yahoo.com', 8471, '2'}, 
 {'john@yahoo.com', 16113, '2'}
  ....
]
```

And I want create new dictionary or list with data grouping by email without use specific name like this:

```
[
 {'sam@yahoo.com', [7007, '1'], [8471, '2']},
 {'john@yahoo.com', 16113, '2'}
  ...
]
```

How I do this? I thought to compare with the next element as in an array, but the list type does not support this syntax

Comment: the data you have is a `list` of `set`s. however `set` is an unordered collection in python, you should either use a list or a dictionary

Comment: Yes. I am afraid I got caught up in the asymmetry of how the entries were being grouped.  However, the primary problem from the start here is the way the data is being represented.  The desired result isn't a dictionary at all, but still represents a list of sets which won't work because the lists aren't hashable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the initial data is a list of lists

```
data_in = [
    ['sam@yahoo.com', 7007, '1'],
    ['sam@yahoo.com', 8471, '2'], 
    ['john@yahoo.com', 16113, '2']
]
```

and the desired result is a dictionary whose keys are the addresses and whose values are a list of lists of

```
{
    'sam@yahoo.com': [[7007, '1'], [8471, '2']],
    'john@yahoo.com': [[16113, '2']]
}
```

I would recommend something like

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_out = defaultdict(list)
for item in data_in:
    data_out[item[0]].append(item[1:3])
```

Comment: that is a lot of assumptions, and do not use `input` as a variable name since that name is already used for a native python function

Comment: @Gugu72, also a good point on the assumptions.  I suspect the real problem the poster is encountering is just that they think they are creating a list when they are creating a set.  I should probably have prompted for a better exposition of the problem, but it was easier to make the long code examples in an answer than in a comment.  And once I started, I figured I should include an actual answer to something.

Comment: @Malcolm. Thanks. This is solution of my problem